# Swift - How to get to Specific Value in nested JSON array

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing

I am trying to get the "image" value string in my nested JSON which I highlighted (events/performers/image)

```
{
   "events":[
      {
         "type":"minor_league_baseball",
         "id":4997345,
         "datetime_utc":"2021-04-20T07:30:00",
         "venue":{
            "state":"FL",
            "name_v2":"Joker Marchant Stadium",
            "postal_code":"33805",
            "name":"Joker Marchant Stadium",
            "links":[
               
            ],
            "timezone":"America\/New_York",
            "url":"https:\/\/seatgeek.com\/venues\/joker-marchant-stadium\/tickets",
            "score":0.689039,
            "location":{
               "lat":28.0739,
               "lon":-81.9533
            },
            "address":"2301 Lakeland Hills Blvd.",
            "country":"US",
            "has_upcoming_events":true,
            "num_upcoming_events":43,
            "city":"Lakeland",
            "slug":"joker-marchant-stadium",
            "extended_address":"Lakeland, FL 33805",
            "id":3929,
            "popularity":0,
            "access_method":null,
            "metro_code":539,
            "capacity":8500,
            "display_location":"Lakeland, FL"
         },
         "datetime_tbd":true,
         "performers":[
            {
               "type":"minor_league_baseball",
               "name":"Lakeland Flying Tigers",
               "image":"https:\/\/seatgeek.com\/images\/performers-landscape\/lakeland-flying-tigers-a24bed\/9431\/huge.jpg",
               "id":9431,
               "images":{
                  "huge":"https:\/\/seatgeek.com\/images\/performers-landscape\/lakeland-flying-tigers-a24bed\/9431\/huge.jpg"
               },
```

I have my structs here, but once I try to go from "performers" to "ImageLink/image" I get a (Value of type '[ImageLink]' has no member 'image') error in my main ViewController

```
import Foundation

struct Entry: Codable {
    let events: [EventsData]
}

struct EventsData: Codable {
    let type: String
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let venue: locationInfo
    let performers: [ImageLink]
}

struct ImageLink: Codable {
    let image: String
}

struct locationInfo: Codable {
    let display_location: String!
//    let state: String
//    let name_v2: String
}
```

I get the error (Value of type '[ImageLink]' has no member 'image') When I am trying to get the specific image String Value.

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    if let url = URL(string:"https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?client_id=MjE3NTI2Nzd8MTYxODg1NzkwOS44ODcxODE4") {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            
            if let data = data {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    do {
                        let parsedJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode(Entry.self, from: data)
                        
                        for entryData in parsedJSON.events {
                            print(entryData.performers.image)
                            print(entryData.id)
                            print(entryData.title)
                            print(entryData.venue.display_location+"\n")
                        }
                        
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
       }.resume()
    }
}
```

}

I am new to JSON, I do apologize for the rookie question :) Thank you in advance for anyone that can help me understand how to do this.

Edit Working:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        if let url = URL(string:"https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?client_id=MjE3NTI2Nzd8MTYxODg1NzkwOS44ODcxODE4") {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                
                if let data = data {
                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                        do {
                            let parsedJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode(Entry.self, from: data)
                            
                            for entryData in parsedJSON.events {
                                print(entryData.id)
                                print(entryData.title)
                                print(entryData.venue.display_location+"\n")
                                print(entryData.performers.first!.image)
                            }
                            
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                }
           }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: performers is an array of a dictionary with five keys.

Answer (score 1):

`performers` is also an array (note the `[]`), you have to use two loops

```
for entryData in parsedJSON.events {
    for performer in entryData.performers {
        print(performer.image)
    }                        
}
```

or if there is only one item

```
for entryData in parsedJSON.events {
    print(entryData.performers.first?.image)                      
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. I edited the text for that code. Because I successfully printed all the other data I needed. So do I have to make a seprate loop just for my "performer.image" data?

Comment: Yes, you have to.

Comment: thank you. It worked. What and how? I only needed to add "print(entryData.performers.first?.image)".Could you explain what the "first?" does and is for?

Comment: It seems I did not have to add 2 loops, but just the "print(entryData.performers.first?.image)" I edited it above. Could you explain?

Comment: The name implies what it is. `first` gets the first item of the array. If there are more they are dropped. The question mark is for safety because the array could be empty

Comment: Thank you buddy. I appreciate it :)